# Can't run Xamarin.iOS application on a device, quits after splash screen

Tags: ios, crash, xamarin.ios, xamarin, startup

This question is not a duplicate of these two, since both are answered and neither one solutions worked in my case.

[App dies on startup but not crash report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898733/app-dies-on-startup-but-not-crash-report)

[Xamarin app crashes on startup on device, works fine in simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406991/xamarin-app-crashes-on-startup-on-device-works-fine-in-simulator)

Whenever I create a brand new Xamarin.iOS application project in Xamarin Studio, and create appropriate Development provisioning profile with Bundle ID for that application, that I set in project's properties, whenever I run the app on a device (try to debug it on there), it shows the splash screen and then the app just quits.

I am providing a log that is being collected when I consequently (without a debugger) am trying to run a deployed app of the phone:

```
Jan 27 23:19:40 Jerico kernel[0] <Notice>: xpcproxy[303] Container: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DF38525E-82C0-443C-BAB3-5C2730E957A4 (sandbox)
Jan 27 23:19:40 Jerico SpringBoard[49] <Warning>: LICreateIconForImage passed NULL CGImageRef image
Jan 27 23:19:40 Jerico locationd[56] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
Jan 27 23:19:42 Jerico ZenKurs[303] <Warning>: Found new TLS offset at 224
Jan 27 23:19:42 Jerico com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:ua.com.cur-cur.zenkurs[0xb6f3][303]) <Warning>: Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Jan 27 23:19:42 Jerico SpringBoard[49] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:ua.com.cur-cur.zenkurs[0xb6f3]' exited voluntarily.
Jan 27 23:19:42 Jerico assertiond[59] <Warning>: Could not set priority of <BKNewProcess: 0x14f61ba60; ua.com.cur-cur.zenkurs; pid: 303; hostpid: -1> to 2, priority: No such process
Jan 27 23:19:42 Jerico assertiond[59] <Warning>: Could not set priority of <BKNewProcess: 0x14f61ba60; ua.com.cur-cur.zenkurs; pid: 303; hostpid: -1> to 4096, priority: No such process
Jan 27 23:19:42 Jerico SpringBoard[49] <Warning>: Unable to deliver -[UIRemoteApplication showTopMostMiniAlertWithSynchronizationPort:] message to port 0: (ipc/send) invalid destination port
Jan 27 23:19:42 Jerico locationd[56] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
Jan 27 23:19:42 Jerico kernel[0] <Notice>: xpcproxy[304] Container: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DF38525E-82C0-443C-BAB3-5C2730E957A4 (sandbox)
Jan 27 23:19:44 Jerico ZenKurs[304] <Warning>: Found new TLS offset at 224
Jan 27 23:19:44 Jerico com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:ua.com.cur-cur.zenkurs[0x785f][304]) <Warning>: Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Jan 27 23:19:44 Jerico SpringBoard[49] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:ua.com.cur-cur.zenkurs[0x785f]' exited voluntarily.
Jan 27 23:19:44 Jerico SpringBoard[49] <Warning>: Unable to deliver -[UIRemoteApplication showTopMostMiniAlertWithSynchronizationPort:] message to port 0: (ipc/send) invalid destination port
```

I am not providing the debug attempt log since it's much larger and mostly contains just debugger entries. Let me know if the debug log is crucial for you to help.

Application works fine on a simulator. I have Xamarin Studio for Mac 5.7 installed, Xamarin.iOS 8.6.0.51 package and the latest XCode with Command Line tools (6.1.1).

P.S. I've tried to set up a provisioning profile for AdHoc distribution (in both provisioning profiles that I mention above I surely add the iPhone (its UUID) I am trying to debug on) and deployed it to device via TestFlight - got the same crash.

I'd appreciate an advise on how to get a more detailed debug info, since the only error I see is

```
Jan 27 23:19:44 Jerico com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:ua.com.cur-cur.zenkurs[0x785f][304]) <Warning>: Service exited with abnormal code: 1
```

which isn't much of a help.

[Debug log from device as gist.](https://gist.github.com/maxpavlov/4f396739248f7f8e4e6f)

[Deploy to device log as gist.](https://gist.github.com/maxpavlov/1ca4cf1dbbdcfb60f3c8)

[Xamarin build log (-v -v -v -v added) as gist.](https://gist.github.com/maxpavlov/b0297fc265c55c2e9782)

Comment: In the context of stackoverflow **latest** version is not very helpful. Please edit your question to include the specific versions (of Xamarin tools and the iOS version of the device). There's also not much useful information, maybe you can add links (e.g. gists) to the debug log and also include the build logs (make sure to add `-v -v -v -v` to the **Additional mtouch arguments** in the project options). Those _might_ prove useful.

Comment: Are you using any 3rd part Libs?

Comment: @poupou, thanks for prompt response. I've added version info and three links to gists that you advised. Although I myself don't see any clue in the new info.

Comment: @DerekBeattie, this is an out-of-the-box iOS application created with iOS single page application project template in Xamarin Studio. Nothing but provisioning profile selected and bundle ID set in iOS Application settings.

Comment: `Xamarin.iOS 8.6.0.51 (dfb682f) Priority Edition` <- this entitles you to direct, priority support from Xamarin. Please your special email address to have an engineer look at this right away (and/or talk with your CSE).

Answer (score 0):

in the iOS build section => linker behavior:
select Don't link for your device.